# Build in Visual Studio Online fails since Azure SDK 2.5

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Since upgrading to Azure SDK 2.5 our CI build is failing. We have an automatic build on Visual Studio Online.

Here's the exception that is being thrown:

> C:\a\src\WebService\WebService.ccproj (82): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are deploying 2.5 on the build machines now. We have it on all of the scale units but one, where we hit an issue. That's under investigation now, and we'll get the roll out finished asap.

Update: We've just finished deploying the new image with 2.5 to all build machines.

Note: You can see a full list of exact versions installed: http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/